# VAST tag url error: Ad error: AdError 1012: Unable to request ads from server due to network error

Tags: xml, google-dfp, vast

I have created a VAST xml version 2 which follows the proper standard. I am  trying to validate it in [vast tag validator](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/vastinspector)

There are two options in the validator. Either to upload VAST tag or VAST XML. I paste the VAST tag (i.e. the link to the xml file) it gives me this error

```
Ad error: AdError 1012: Unable to request ads from server due to network error.
```

However, when I paste the xml itself into the VAST xml field option, the ad runs perfectly fine. I cannot share the xml because of security reasons. Is there a way to tell what possibly could be the problem?

Comment: IMA Inspector throws that error for example if you tag does not deliver via HTTPS. In case you _did_ use HTTPS, could you share the tag?

Comment: @Zero2 I tried both http and https....gives me the same error. I can actually share an alterated tag not the actual one cos of security issues if that would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced `(10:51:46) Ad error: AdError 1012: Unable to request ads from server due to network error.` issue.

After review of console errors I figured out the issue was related to `CORS`.

[image: Console when use VAST tag]

Then I added  `https://imasdk.googleapis.com` to allowed origins list of my API and the issue was solved. Hope this is the root cause for you as well

Comment: in fact I have the same cause. Thanks a lot. Can you be more elaborate on how you solved it?